# Setting .htaccess to go to https and php instead of html

Tags: .htaccess

I have my hosting with 1and1, I have just got a SSL certificate. I currently have changed the .htaccess to load .php files instead of html files which works fine with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

#remove the need for .php extention 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Now I want the site to load with https, regardless of if it is entered like `http://www` or `http://` etc. I am getting so many different ways to do this from various places as most same that I am supplying duplicate sites if I don't specify either `http://` or `http://www`. So I think I will be solving 2 problems in one go. The code 1and1 supply is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.sitename\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.sitename.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this does not seem to do much on its own? Can I conbine the 2 to simply load https://www.site for everything and change all links to load .php.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}


RewriteEngine on
#remove the need for .php extention 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```